# Handling a Webservice stream in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, streaming, wso2

Good day guys.

I need to consume a webservice that works as a file streaming (it receives a file Id and returns the file via stream).

Then in PHP I must handle this process. I have been looking for a solution on how to do this since, as far as I know, the native soap client in PHP does not have these capabilities.

I found WSO2 (Web Services Framework for PHP) which handles Binary attachment ( MTOM ).

I'm yet to test it, but the real question is, based on your experience, what would be the smartest approach for consuming a webservice with these characteristics?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2):

`WSO2 WSF/PHP` is a better more sophisticated of doing file streaming using `MTOM` which is a standard that other languages support.

`MTOM` uses `base64` to encode files which you can implement on your on if you don't want yo use `WSO2`

Am not sure why you want `stream` please note that you can always open any file as`stream` so far you have a copy of that files so i don't think that is the most important .. what is key is sending the file `safely` to the server

Example using `SoapClient`

Client

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$client=new SoapClient(PATH_TO_WSDL,array('encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1'));
$data = file_get_contents(PATH_TO_FILE);
$ret = $client->recieveFile(base64_encode($data));
```

Server

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

const  PATH_TO_WSDL = "b.php?wsdl" ;
$client=new SoapClient(PATH_TO_WSDL,array('encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1'));
$data = file_get_contents(PATH_TO_FILE);
$ret = $client->recieveFile(base64_encode($data));
```

Please note that `base64` would increase the file by `33%` it advisable to spit the files into chunks for very large files

Comment: I decided to use WSO2 framework. The documentation is not extensive, but after researching seemed like the best approach. Thank you very much Baba.